# Matrice 100 - On Board SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

For my M100 I want to control several external devices such as laserpointer or thermal camera. I think, for a full control I have to integrate it by OSDK. I looked through the dji sdk documentation, but I have no idea where to start and what I effectively have to do. May somebody give me a little hint how to start and what really is necessary to fullfill my requirement described below.

1. Connect a Flir Boson (3.3V) and display the thermal image on the remote controllers mobile device.
2. Control the thermal camera (switch on/off) by the remote conroller.
3. Connect a laser pointer on a standard port of the M100 and control switch it on/off by a button of the remote controller.